# How to apply landscape mode for Game Center View Controller in iOS6

Tags: uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, uiapplication

I am working with COCOS2D game. Now i have updated my game to iOS6. I have seen that Apple has changed Game Center login(authentication) process. So for that i have used handler authenticateWithCompletionHandler and nw my game is crashing.

I have also solved this issue via adding method.

`- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}`

That fixed my crash. But now issue is Game-Center authentication view comes only in portrait mode. As my whole game is in Landscape mode. i want that authentication view in Landscape.

Does anyone provide me any solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your app should support landscape and portrait mode if you are using landscape mode with Game Center in iOS6. Otherwise your app will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no landscape view for the authentication screen in Game Center for iOS6.

Whether this was an oversight by Apple or deliberate we don't know. Many people are expecting a fix to come with the next release but it is just hearsay at the moment.

All you can do is what you have already done. It is possible to only allow portrait for iOS6 small screen devices as a workaround. Any device running iOS5 and iPads don't have to be in portrait and should function correctly.